# Помогите настроить почтовый сервер postfix

Tags: сервер, email, postfix

поставил почтовый сервер на отдельную каплю на digital ocean и соответсвено подключил домен.
Так же на яндексе сделал почту домена.
Начал ставить и настраивать почтовый сервер (но при его проверке введя команду echo "hello body!" | mail -s "Hello subject!" yaroslav*******@mail.ru

НА почту ничего не приходит, и в логах следующие (статус равен не отправке а противоположному значению, и в realy нет mx записи почты на которую идет отправка) в чем я допустил ошибку (если информации мало, напишите чно нужно еще написать, благодарю за помощь!
Запись в логах

```
root@mail-*****bary:~# tail -f /var/log/mail.log
Apr 11 15:06:49 mail-*****tbary postfix/smtp[2962]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c09::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Apr 11 15:07:06 mail-*****bary postfix/smtp[2926]: 3562B81CCA: to=<yaroslav*****@mail.ru>, relay=none, delay=60, delays=0.02/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status =deferred (connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.104]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Comment: Судя по логам, smtp-клиент не может установить соединение с хостами из интернет. Смотрите настройки сети/ правила фильтрации сетевых пакетов. Попробуйте зайти консолью и набрать `telnet mxs.mail.ru 25`

Comment: введя эту команду все останавливается на этом " root@mail-*****bary:~# telnet mxs.mail.ru 25
Trying 94.100.180.104...

Comment: Иногда еще второй айпи появляется, в логах ничего

Comment: выйти из телнет - нажать `Ctrl + ]` и `набрать quit`. У вас, на текущий момент, проблема с сетевыми подключениями вашего хоста наружу, а не с posttfix. Разбираться нужно с этим

Comment: Извиняюсь, возможно чего то не понимаю, но команда не найдена(